# Role Management using Azure RBAC

Tags: c#, azure, rbac

I am using AAD for authentication. but for role management I am planning to use Azure Custom roles. But I am not able to get any resource with proper guidance. Is this it possible to use azure roles for web role management?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Roles are for authorising access to Azure resources. You can define custom roles as per this guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles

Any AD principal can be assigned these roles. Whether it's user or application.

Otherwise I'm a little confused as to your question. You mentioned "web role management" but it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Please describe in more detail the problem you are trying to solve.